# What does P mean in Go's sync.Pool source code?

Tags: go

Recently, I've been digging into Go's source code. When I looked into the details of sync.Pool, I found a comment I couldn't understand.

https://golang.org/src/sync/pool.go?s=1633:1992#L58

```
// Local per-P Pool appendix.
type poolLocalInternal struct {
    private interface{}   // Can be used only by the respective P.
    shared  []interface{} // Can be used by any P.
    Mutex                 // Protects shared.
}
```

> Local per-P Pool appendix.

What does per-P mean?

> Can be used only by the respective P

What does P mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

P stands for processor. A processor is a resource used to execute Go code. There are exactly GOMAXPROC Ps in a process. [The Go Scheduler Design Doc](https://golang.org/s/go11sched) describes Ps in detail. The relevant code is in the [runtime package](https://golang.org/src/runtime/).